# GET/POST通信でcookieをやり取りし、ログイン処理

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cookie, https

google apps scriptを使用しています。

あるサイトへのログイン処理を行っています。

```
var LOGIN_URL = "**********"; 
var userid = "*********"; 
var password = "***********";
var source_URL = "************";

var options = {
  method : "post",
  followRedirects: true,
  contentType: "applicationxml; charset=utf-8",
  payload : {
    userId: userid,
    password: password
  }
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(LOGIN_URL, options);
var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
```

上記のようにオプションを設定し、ログインを行いました。
そして、取得したヘッダー情報の中に、

> Set-Cookie=[Ljava.lang.Object;@6eee775a, Vary=Accept-Encoding, X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, Content-Type=text/html; charset=utf-8}

があります。
それをまた、変数cookiesに格納しています。

```
if ( typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] !== 'undefined' ) {
  var cookies = typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] == 'string' ? [ headers['Set-Cookie'] ] : headers['Set-Cookie'];
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      cookies[i] = cookies[i].split( '; ' )[0];
  };
}
```

その結果

> cookies[0]:tracking_code=eafdc5ca82ea6d8bfc0b1d147efc6efefe31e2f5
>   cookies[1]:_huntr_session_production=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%3D--32990cfc8da6226e010f8d53f3f4fcdbe516b7c3

となっています。
そして、cookiesをpostメソッドで渡して、ログイン処理を行います。

```
var options2 = {
  method: "get",
  followRedirects: true,
  headers: {
    Cookie: cookies.join('; ')
  }
};

var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(source_URL, options2);
var headers2 = source.getAllHeaders();
var content = source.getContentText();
```

しかし、contentをスプレッドシート上で出力すると、ログインしていない状態のページのHTMLが表示されます。

質問は以下の通りです。
①何が原因でログインされていないのでしょうか。
⓶コードのどの部分を変更すべきでしょうか。
⓷コードが特に間違っていない場合でしたら、そもそもログイン処理の方法が間違っているのでしょうか。（認証方式による違いなど）。その場合、どのような方法をとるべきでしょうか。

何か足りない情報などがございましたら、ご返信にてお伝えします。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: サーバ側のログは見ることができますか？CSRFトークンで弾かれているとか、可能性がありすぎて回答が難しいです。GASの問題なのか、それ以前なのか切り分ける必要が有ると思います。 まずは、curl でログインできるかどうか調べてみてはいかがでしょうか？ ` curl -XPOST LOGIN_URL -d "userId:userId" -d "password:password"` など。

Comment: ご丁寧にご回答ありがとうございます。サーバー側のログは見られません。また、curlでもログイン出来ませんでした。自分でも他の可能性を調べてみます。

Answer (score 1):

followRedirects: true　ではなく、リダイレクトを一つ一つ自分で処理しないと無理かもね。

CRSFトークンなんて、Cookieに織り込んである運用がほとんどでしょう。
curlのコマンドにしたって、例にあげてるのは、Cookieオプション付いてないし。